# Bigquery data transfer duration from intraday table to daily table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using firebase analytics and bigguery with average of 50~60 GB daily data.

For the most recent daily table, a query gives different result from yesterday even if query conditions are exact same including target date.

I just found that there are 1~2days gap between table creation date and last modified date.

I assume the difference between the query results are because of this. (Calculating on different data volume, maybe)

Is this date gap means a single daily table needs at least 2 days to be fully loaded from intraday table?

Thanks in advance.

[biqguery table info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wybem.png)

Answer (score 1):

In the [documentation](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6318765?hl=en) we can find the following information:

> After you link a project to BigQuery, the first daily export of
>   events creates a corresponding dataset in the associated BigQuery
>   project. Then, each day, raw event data for each linked app populates
>   a new daily table in the associated dataset, and raw event data is
>   streamed into a separate intraday BigQuery table in real-time.

It seems that the intraday table is loaded to the main table each day and if you want to access this data in real-time you`ll have to use this intraday separate  table.

If this information doesn`t help you, please provide some extra information so I can help you more efficiently.

Comment: thank you for the help, rmesteves 
when i run the query, i used past dates which suppose to have full data for one day. 
(ex. run the query for 2019-12-28 data on 2019-12-29 or later)

Since the query result for 2019-12-29 data on 12-30 and 12-31 was different( even session count were different),
I was wonder if the daily event table need days to fully uploaded from intraday table.

Any ideas? thanks.

Comment: It looks like this is common as can see here (https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/real-time-exporting-of-analytics-data-into-bigquery.html).  It can take up to 24 hours to load the complete daily data and also depends on the timezone of your applications.